# Why does my if statement return false when I am checking the amount of items in a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am working on [this](https://www.codewars.com/kata/55d8aa568dec9fb9e200004a/train/python) CodeWars Kata and just to get started I decided to split the given numbers into individual list items to check and see if the amount of digits was 2 or greater but when I run this code block it returns false even though when I print the resultant list out it has more than one item in the list. I believe the function should be returning my print statement of "numbers not asc".

Am I missing something super obvious?

```
def sel_number(n, d):
#converts digits into individual ints and then converts those into strings and loads into a list
    first_num = [int(a) for a in str(n)]
    second_num = [int(b) for b in str(d)]
    #check if length of list is 2 or more otherwise return false
    if len(first_num) or len(second_num) <= 1:
        return False
    #check if numbers in list are ascending
    elif first_num != sorted(first_num) or second_num != sorted(second_num):
        print('numbers not asc')
    else: 
        return True

sel_number(21, 21)
```

Comment: You might have wanted `len(first_num) <= 1 or len(second_num) <= 1` instead.

Comment: `if len(first_num) or len(second_num) <= 1` is the problem.  This means `if (len(first_num)) or (len(second_num) <=1)`.  The first part of that `if` statement is true, because `len(first_num)` is 2, and a non-zero number is treated as True (it's "truthy") for these purposes in Python.

Comment: Aha! So it was something super obvious but I also learned something new so, thank you!!